# Load ads after content is loaded

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, adsense

I am trying to load AdSense responsive ads after content is loaded from Firebase, however no ads are showing, just blank pace. After putting code online I get error:

> No slot size for availableWidth=0

I went through about 4 pages in google to find solution but couldn't get one so I thought you can help me out.

I am applying the AdSense code as following:

```
    <head>
       <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="demo" style="display: none;">
       <!-- SnusPedia automatic size add -->
       <style>
          .example_responsive_1 { width: 320px; height: 100px; }
          @media(min-width: 500px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
          @media(min-width: 800px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
       </style>
       <ins class="adsbygoogle example_responsive_1"
          style="display:block"
          data-ad-client="ca-pub-8297030761327810"
          data-ad-slot="9809929086"
          data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
       <script>
             window.onload = function(){
            (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
             }
       </script>
  </div>

    </body>
```

What could cause the problem?

Comment: Is everything wrapped in `<div id="demo" style="display: none;">`? I don't see closing `</div>` tag

Comment: Yep, everything is wrapped in `<div id="demo" style="display: none;">` and actually I have closing tag also just type in question.

Comment: So when are you removing the `display: none`?

Comment: @Morpheus after Firebase query is done.

Answer (score 0):

AdSense won't show an ad if it is hidden or has a width/height of 0, which happens in your case because of your surrounding `div#demo`. It is completely hidden so AdSense can't fill an ad since there is no space available. Try removing the `display: none` from `#demo`.

Additionally, it is not allowed to load ads on a custom event which means that it may be against Google's TOS to show the ad after waiting for the firebase query.

I could imagine that you could remove the script tag which loads `adsbygoogle.js`, then wait for your firebase query and load `adsbygoogle.js` – however I doubt that Google allows this.

I would recommend you to simply remove the `display: none` from the outer div and just load the ad regardless of whether your firebase query has finished or not.